# The quaternion group $Q_{8} := \{1,−1, i,−i, j,−j, k,−k \}$ of $\mathbb{H} $ is a group under multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quaternions

The quaternion group $Q_{8} := \{1,−1, i,−i, j,−j, k,−k \}$ of $\mathbb{H} $ is  a group under multiplication.

> **Which of the following Wedderburn  decomposition of $\mathbb{C} [Q_{8}]$ is correct? Why?Please help me.**

$\mathbb{C} [Q_{8}] \cong  M_{2}(\mathbb{C}) \times M_{2} ( \mathbb{C})$

$\mathbb{C} [Q_{8}] \cong  M_{2}(\mathbb{C}) \times  \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} $

Comment: Besides the trivial representation, there are three "sign" representations $Q_8\to\{\pm1\}$ corresponding to the three cyclic (normal) subgroups generated by $i$, $j$ and $k$.

Answer (score 2):

The Wedderburn decomposition of a group ring $\Bbb C G$ for a finite
group $G$ always has a copy of $\Bbb C$ (corresponding to the trivial
representation). That knocks out one of your possible structures...